# Find name related to ID and add to bind to DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

### Issue

---

I am having an issue where some of the properties in a class are stored as ID's but I want to display the related ID's name instead of the ID.

### Code

---

So I have a `ObservableCollection<Chapter> EpisodeList` which I have bound to my `DataGrid`. In `Chapter` I have a property called **AppearanceID**. When I bind this to my `DataGrid` displays the ID.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding EpisodeList}"

Global.gEpisodeList = Global.gSeries.ChapterList.ToList();
Global.gEpisodeList.ForEach(a => EpisodeList.Add(a));
```

I have stored a list of Appearances in a variable called `Global.Appearance` where the ID and the names are stored.

```
Global.Appearance = Global.podiaClient.GetAppearances(Global.podiaSession).ToList();
```

What I am looking to do is instead of the DataGrid displaying the ID. I want it to check the `Global.Appearance` list and get the name and display that instead.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: will post some code more?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to create a new object that combines the data. If the data is read only, you can copy values. If you want editability, create call through properties, with `Chapter`/`Episode` as a value store.